# There is a set of continuous functions $f$ on [0, 1] with supremum metric (metric space). Proof that $\phi(f) = f(0) + f(1)$ is continous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the set $C([0, 1]) = \{f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} : f$ is continuous }, with the supremum metric $d_{sup}$
$$d_{sup}(f, g) = sup{|f(x) - g(x)| : x \in [0, 1]}$$

Let $\phi : C([0, 1]) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by the formula:
$\phi(f) = f(0) + f(1)$

Prove that $\phi$ is continuous.

---

I don't know how to apply that metric to function $\phi$. Taking to $\phi$ different functions $f$ (that are continous on $x ∈ [0, 1]$) I will get different values at those ends of interval: f(0), f(1). But how /where do I use the supremum metric (that expresses an abstract category of distance between 2 random functions, but in my $\phi$ I have only one function and sum, not difference)? I am confused, how does $\phi$ look like whith that metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just like showing that any other function is continuous.

Fix $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

We need to find $\delta>0$ such that for $g\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with $d_{\sup}(f,g)<\delta$, we have
$$|\phi(f)-\phi(g)|=|f(1)+f(0)-(g(1)+g(0))|\leq |f(1)-g(1)|+|f(0)-g(0)|<\varepsilon$$

Hopefully this puts you on the right track. I will leave it to you to choose the correct $\delta$.

Comment: Taking a supremum on x of both absolute values on the left side of the equation we get: $|f(1) - g(1) | + |f(0) + g(0)| < \delta + \delta = 2\delta$. Now, for $\delta = \frac{1}{4} \varepsilon$ we get $2\delta =  \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon < \varepsilon$. Is that it?

Comment: you can just let $\delta=\varepsilon/2$, but yes this works as well

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So every time I need to remember that I want to change the existing function in question to such form that I could use my metric to estimate it right $\delta$ to make it to the definition with $\varepsilon$. That scheme of thinking does not depend on particular metric space. Am I right?

Comment: its just applying the definition of continuity. If $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ provided that $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in X:d_X(x,x_0)<\delta\Longrightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$$

it shouldn't matter that the elements of the metric space are functions themselves. they are just points in the metric space

Comment: Cool, I think I get it. I'll read some more. Thank you Sir.